# Minor concerns about the new question side-bar content

Tags: discussion, sidebar

I'm posting a question on Seasoned Advice and saw this:

[image: Side bar picture]

This seems off for a couple reasons:

- One, it seems odd to have code formatting instructions on the side bar of a cooking site. Even if it was accepted to format recipes or something as code, calling it "code" seems weird.
- And, even on Stack Overflow it shouldn't be necessary to include the language with the code fence unless that particular code is for a language other than the tagged language. This is also outright irrelevant information on Seasoned Advice.

In both cases, it seems to be supplying more information than necessary, which isn't great for new users trying to absorb what they can. I think the code instructions should be removed from sites that have nothing to do with programming, and it's mentioned that tagging is also sufficient for highlighting on the relevant sites. If a user needs multiple different highlighting schemes in a single question, I'd say in most cases it's a new user posting a "translate" question, so the question is likely offtopic anyway.

---

Side note, how do I shrink images? Do I need to save them as smaller in the first place? They always come out needlessly huge.

Comment: _“how do I shrink images?”_ — you can try adding `m` before `.jpg`, so `https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIlwR.jpg` becomes `https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIlwRm.jpg`. Then you can use `[![Side bar picture][2]][1]`, keep link `[1]` at the bottom, but use `[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIlwRm.jpg`.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't hesitate to call this a bug. There is no reason to show how to format something as code on a cooking site. Also, it looks like this happens on other sites. I only sampled Travel.SE, Bicyles.SE, and Gaming.SE, and the code formatting info shows on all of them. Note you have to click on the body textarea for that formatting sidebar to show up.

Comment: @Xufox Hmm, doesn't seem to have worked, although I may have fubared it. Now that you mention the link though, I remember that there are a few minimized links that you can use for Imgur. I'll see if I can remember what they are.

Comment: @Xufox That's currently not working in most cases. Resizing currently requires using HTML size constraints.

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment after your comment. But I just checked a bunch of sites and it looks like they all have it. Note that you have to click on the body textarea for the formatting instructions to show up.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Ya, that was the problem. Thanks. I'll edit.

Comment: I saw this guidance on Writing *Meta* earlier.  I'd guess that code belongs on most metas even less than it belongs on their corresponding main sites.

Comment: Similar discussion on SOja (in Japanese): https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2971