# "How to format" block mentions syntax highlighting even if it is not available on the site

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

When you edit the *body* of a post, the "How to Format" widget is shown in the right sidebar. It mentions the syntax highlighting function, even on [sites which don't have syntax highlighting enabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314554/295232) like [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask):

[image]

It's probably also a good idea to move the part about code fences down for non-technical sites (like [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)); other formatting options are more important there.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325719/312043